# Wrapping a class while still exposing all its public methods, properties and fields

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm trying to make a generic wrapper class that can wrap any other class and add extra functionality to it. However at the same time I want to be able to use this wrapper everywhere where I would normally use the wrapped class. Currently I use implicit casting which works OK. But in an ideal world I would like to the wrapper class to have the same exposed methods and fields as the wrapped class, like in this piece of example code:

```
class Foo
{   
    public int Bar() { return 5; }
}

class Wrapper<T>
{
    private T contents;

    public void ExtraFunctionality() { }
    public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> w) { return w.contents; }
}



Foo f = new Foo();
Wrapper<Foo> w = new Wrapper<Foo>(foo);

int y = w.Bar();
```

Can I use some ancient witchcraft, reflection, or other trickery to make this possible?

Note: in C++ I would just overload the -> operator to operate on the field contents instead of on the wrapper.

Comment: Sounds like a decorated proxy. Using T4 to generate the wrapped classes an option?

Comment: It's a guess, but have you tried `public class Wrapper<T> : T`? I don't know if it is possible though.

Comment: @Silvermind No that's not possible.

Comment: @Iboshuizen I'm not using it in a web context but I hadn't considered code generation yet. That might be a viable solution though I'd prefer a pure C# solution since that is easier to debug/ship/maintain.

Comment: A wrapped class can't expose methods that are not explicit part of his definition imho. Perhaps [dynamic] can come to the rescue, but by using T4 you have early binding. Besides T4 is not a solely for the web.

Comment: Take a look at [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this, but since you've mentioned witchcraft... you can use dynamic typing with `DynamicObject`. The wrapper tries to handle the requested method. If it can't, it forwards the call to the underlying wrapped object:

```
class DynamicWrapper : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly object _contents;

    public DynamicWrapper(object obj)
    {
        _contents = obj;
    }

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        if (binder.Name == "ExtraFunctionality")
        {
            // extra functionality
            return true;
        }
        var method = _contents.GetType()
                             .GetRuntimeMethods()
                             .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == binder.Name);

        if (method == null)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }

        result = method.Invoke(_contents, args);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

Nevermind, I just noticed you wanted to use an instance of this everywhere where you would normally use an instance of the wrapped type.
You'd have to change the field/property/variable declaration to `dynamic` to use this.

Comment: As long as I can write a cast overload for this it should be OK. I'm gonna try it out tomorrow! (I also wonder what the overhead is for this, any idea?)

Comment: By the way, you'll also need to override `TryGetMember` and `TrySetMember` to get/set properties of the wrapped instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "a cast overload"? The overhead is not that high, I remember reading a post by Eric Lippert on this, i think a piece of dynamic code will be compiled at runtime and then cached whenever possible.

Comment: The line `public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> w) { return w.contents; }` in my example. Overloading casting so to speak.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I went with having the user do it manually, but I really learned something new from this and it was also a proper solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the type(s) dynamically using the classes in the [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) namespace. This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121568/Dynamic-Type-Using-Reflection-Emit) can give you a good starting point.

Comment: But that will change the interface at runtime, while for doing w.Bar() I need the interface to be known at compile time.

Comment: The interface is not necessarily changed if the generated types derive from the wrapped types or implement the same interfaces. However, you might need to inject your wrapper classes in the client classes to allow to inject the wrapper classes instead of the original ones. Some IoC frameworks implement interceptions to allow running code before or after certain methods with that approach.